# Create a tuple from an input in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, tuples

Here is my example:

```
>>> a=input ('some text : ')  # value entered is 1,1
>>> print (a)
1,1
```

I want as a result a tuple   (1, 1)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16):

You could do something like

```
a = tuple(int(x) for x in a.split(","))
```

Answer (score 10):

You could interpret the input as Python literals with [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

a = ast.literal_eval(input('some text: '))
```

This function will accept any input that look like Python literals, such as integers, lists, dictionaries and strings:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('1,1')
(1, 1)
```

Comment: I used this function in one of my programs to take tuple input as well, so I wrapped it with the tuple() function and put it all in a try/except case to prevent things like functions being entered as input and insure that only tuples were entered

Comment: @samrap: `ast.literal_eval()` doesn't support entering functions. Only literals are supported; strings, booleans, numbers, lists, tuples, dictionaries and `None`. That's it.

Comment: @samrap: You can always use a more explicit method (like jonrsharpe posted) or use `isinstance(result, tuple)` to ensure that only tuples are being entered.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in the following way.

```
a = '3, 5, 7, 23'

out = tuple(map(int, a.split(",")))

print(out)

(3, 5, 7, 23)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple.

```
 tup = tuple(input("enter tuple"))
 print(tup)
```

This will work.

Comment: It will not really work. The input is a string, and passing that to `tuple()` will create a tuple from the string's characters. So for example, for the OP's input of `1,1`, your code will output `('1', ',', '1')`

Answer (score -2):

```
>>> a = input()
(21, 51, 65, 45, 48, 36, 8)
>>> m = eval(a)
>>> type(m)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Eval has its own drawback

Comment: This is not a good option: please review [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/7758804). `ast.literal_eval` is already posted as an answer here.